# How to take advantage of m2m relations when using order_with_respect_to in an intermediary table in Django?

Tags: django-models

I've recently discovered the sequencing of related objects with the meta option `order_with_respect_to`, which does spare me a lot of troubles. Now I want to use it for m2m fields through an intermediary table. Simply enough, here's my code:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(to=Foo, through=Intermediary, related_name="bars")

class Intermediary(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(to=Foo, ...)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(to=Bar, ...)
    somestuff = models.CharField(...)

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = "foo"
```

And as far as I've tested, it seems to work well, as long as I create the relationships by directly creating an instance of the `Intermediary` model: `Intermediary(foo=some_foo, bar=some_bar, somestuff="Hello")`.

Now what I'd really much like to do is to take full advantage of the m2m relations and create the relationship indirectly like so: `some_bar.foos.add(some_foo, through_defaults={"somestuff": "Hello"})`
But here's problem: the `_order` column needs to be set somehow, and it's not automatically in this case:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: core_intermediary._order
```

What is the internal automatic sequencing method of `Intermediary` and how can I call it? Or is there another option that doesn't require me modifying `Foo`?

Comment: Do you get the same result with `bulk=False` in the `add` method?
I can't try it myself for now.

Comment: [Django 3.1's documentation for the `.add` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) reads: "Using add() with a many-to-many relationship, however, will not call any save() methods (**the bulk argument doesn’t exist**)". In the next section it refers to the use of signals for "custom logic" when creation a relationship, which I feel might be the start of an idea, but some sections over it refers to the use of `through_defaults` with callable values, which I'm keener to use if possible, but I am confused as how.

Comment: Oops, I should have read the docs more carefully, sorry. However, you problem might be related with this. I suspect `through_defaults` won't be of any help there as the `foo` and `bar` fields are already populated by Django. The issue probably is, as you guessed, that the `save` method is not called by `add`, and therefore the NOT NULL constrain fails as `_order` is not populated at the time objects are added to the relation.   Trying to run `save` on `pre_add` signal might confirm this.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why no save() methods are called in this case, as an `Intermediary` instance is created anyway and must be saved into the database for the whole thing to have any meaning at all, and why using `through_defaults` wouldn't make the `_order` field, well, default to whatever it would normally.
Anyway, my solution so far is the following:
`last_order = some_foo.bars.order_by().last()._order` then `some_bar.foos.add(some_foo, through_defaults={"somestuff": "Hello", "_order": last_order + 1})`
That seems to work but it's inelegant, I suppose...